# Why does hot air from my fan heater stop after 4 to 7 seconds?

Tags: electrical, thermostat, fans, heater

Product: [Challenge fan heater: model E9907R-N -- 230-240V -- 50 Hz -- 2750-3000W](http://www.argos.co.uk/product/4152590).

While off, something fell through the grid.
I opened the fan heater to remove it.
It now doesn't blow hot air (setting 1 or 2) for more then 4/7 seconds.
Cold air is fine.

It seems to me that the thermostat function is playing up but I'm not an electrician, the warranty is gone, I cannot afford a new one and according to GOT: "Winter is coming"

I've attached 1 photo as I'm not allowed to post more than 2 links.

I've circled what seems to be the thermostat (1) and where the trigger to stop the fan is (2). If the trigger is opened the fan doesn't work but when closed it does. Nothing is/has burned.

Here is #1 that I thought would be a kind of thermostat or resistance.

[image: Thermostat or Resistance]

[image: Fan Heater Top View]

If something had burned I would have understood.
I've 'only' moved an object out of the way. It still works for cold air and also starts blowing hot air for 4 to 7 seconds until the trigger 'click' (sound) open. Then I have to wait (2 min approx) for the thermostat (non-damaged) to cool down (I guess), the click sound happens again and the trigger is closed and it's ready to go again for a few seconds. Turning the thermostat button does not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

#2 is not a thermostat.  It is a thermal protection safety device, and the usual culprit in cheap Cheese heaters.  I can trip if the heater is failing and the protective device is behaving correctly, or the device has failed.

I would test it by wiring any 240V lamp, such as a small neon light(available as a component) between its terminals (parallel with it). It will act as a fault light, in normal conditions it should not light.

Don't even think of running without it.  It is an important safety device.  However you may be able to get markings off it and find a replacement on electronic component web sites in the neighborhood of 1-2 quid plus shipping.

This is a cheap heater and it should be expected to fail after a year or two.  If you can't afford cheap, buy quality.

Comment: Hi Harper, thanks! #1 was the 'thermostat' in my mind (not #2). I'm not an electrician so I definitely get all the wording wrong haha. I bought this heating fan in 2013 I think and I confess I used it a lot! It's only after I opened it to remove what had fallen inside that it stopped behaving correctly so I thought I moved something. I'm not sure how to apply your solution. Do you think you would please be able to redirect me to a website where I can learn how to do that? Indeed I can't afford quality at the moment. Sorry and thanks again!

Comment: Neither one is a thermostat, that is one of the two knobs.  I don't know where to tell you to go to start climbing the learning curve of electrical... **Sparkfun** maybe?  Anyway you will need either money or skills, for this and life in general, so unless you have a sugar daddy, you'll want to make your life about learning.

Comment: Haha Thanks Harper! And Thanks to Niall C. ♦ as well. Then I broke something while opening it. My bad. Sparkfun here I come!

Answer (score 0):

Is surely the 'PTC' resistor (in this case used as 'auto-resetting fuse') that detected a short circuit on the heating coils. You'd better to throw that heater and buy new one as it seem not to be safe for use any more.